# VMware Tools for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, ubuntu-16.04

Anybody knows how to get VMware Tools working for the latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial?

I've been using the patches from [here](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches/)
for my Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid, which works fine. But not any more for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial. Error enclosed below.

Without VMware Tools working, I'm unable to see the `hgfs` shared from the host.

Looking up the error, from [github](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/44), it says

> With open-vm-tools 10.0, there is no need to build vmhgfs module anymore. This is not required because HGFS implementation is FUSE based in 10.0.

So I removed VMware Tools, then installed the official `open-vm-tools`:

```
$ apt-cache policy open-vm-tools
open-vm-tools:
  Installed: 2:10.0.7-3227872-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2:10.0.7-3227872-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2:10.0.7-3227872-2ubuntu2 500
...

$ apt-cache search hgfs | wc 
      0       0       0

$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              481988       0    481988   0% /dev
tmpfs              99852    4548     95304   5% /run
/dev/sda1       31863728 1699600  28522504   6% /
tmpfs             499248       0    499248   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             499248       0    499248   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

But, I'm still unable to see the `hgfs` shared from the host.

Thanks

```
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:59:21: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
.follow_link   = HgfsFollowlink,
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:59:21: note: (near initialization for ‘HgfsLinkInodeOperations.follow_link’)
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:61:21: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
.put_link      = HgfsPutlink,
                 ^
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:61:21: note: (near initialization for ‘HgfsLinkInodeOperations.put_link’)
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c: In function ‘HgfsFollowlink’:
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:127:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘nd_set_link’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
      nd_set_link(nd, fileName);
      ^
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c: In function ‘HgfsPutlink’:
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:276:15: error: implicit  declaration of function ‘nd_get_link’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
fileName = nd_get_link(nd);
           ^
/tmp/modconfig-VJIcMa/vmhgfs-only/link.c:276:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
fileName = nd_get_link(nd);
         ^

$ uname -a 
Linux uname 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the "vmhgfs-fuse" command.

I was able to do the following:

I made a directory to mount the hgfs share, let's call it ~/vmshare. Then I did:

```
vmhgfs-fuse ~/vmshare
```

On my system, with the same version of open-vm-tools that you are using, that properly mounted the shared disk into ~/vmshare/.

If you do not want the share in your user's home directory, you'll probably have to use sudo and additional parameters to vmhgfs-fuse.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick! Welcome aboard, with my +25 points, :-).

Comment: Finally comes the right simple solution.

Comment: Oh God yes, this was it. The simplest command is the only one that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much - this worked, so I did :

i) I shared the folder on  Win7

ii) Followed this part of the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/29284/how-do-i-mount-shared-folders-in-ubuntu-using-vmware-tools

sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs

The -d selects all the defaults for you (remove it if you don't want the defaults).

iii) Then followed this from this link

[Check out the "vmhgfs-fuse" command.

I was able to do the following:

I made a directory to mount the hgfs share, let's call it ~/vmshare. Then I did:

vmhgfs-fuse ~/vmshare
On my system, with the same version of open-vm-tools that you are using, that properly mounted the shared disk into ~/vmshare/.

If you do not want the share in your user's home directory, you'll probably have to use sudo and additional parameters to vmhgfs-fuse.]

---

Word of advise - this worked at this time - but ???